# How to store many files in one file without using compression

Tags: windows, compression

If I have a large set of small files it takes Windows a long time to copy them (say five minutes) due to the overhead per file. If I wrap them up in a container it transfers them much faster (say three minutes).

Currently I use UltraISO. But after adding many files to the ISO it becomes too slow creating the ISO file itself.

I don't want to use Zip because the overhead of zipping is slower than just transferring the files separately.

How else can I store many files in one file without using any compression?

Comment: The [`tar`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm) utility is what you are looking for. Originally from Unix, GNU has pre-compiled binaries available for Windows. It archives files together in one big file, with _optional_ compression, using zip, gzip, bzip, 7-zip, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much @ScottChamberlain . That's the question I want to ask...

Answer (score 7):

I would still recommend zipping the file, however when you create the zip you need to choose to use the "store" compression settings (or whatever equivalent your software calls it)

[image]

This wraps all the items and puts them in a container but performs no compression on them. This is a very fast opperation (I will get 30 MB/s in "store" mode vs 2 MB/s in "fastest" mode)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But 30MB per second -it's still too slow. Try ultra iso ( integrate with mouse right click button[win shell] and go to a folder > click mouse right button > click "add nameoffile.iso with ultraiso" ) It's very fast but not enough. Also, windows 8 is native iso file support. So you can move&use your files without a program.